# Django unhandled exception response status code

Tags: django, django-views

Running django 1.3. If I have an unhandled exception in a view, e.g.

```
def test(request):
    raise Exception('error')
```

GETing the page (here via wget):

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'

    [ <=>                                   ] 218         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2011-08-04 17:47:43 (14.9 MB/s) - `index.html' saved [218]
```

Contents of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>Unhandled Exception</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unhandled Exception</h1>
<p>An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.</p>
</body></html>
```

And now to the question: why is the response status code 200? It should be 500.

EDIT: 
Run on lighttpd with command

```
manage.py runfcgi --settings=$SETTINGS socket=$SOCKET pidfile=$PIDFILE method=prefork minspare=1 maxspare=1 maxchildren=10 maxrequests=100"
```

DEBUG=FALSE in settings.py. If I change to DEBUG=TRUE, the response status code is correctly 500.

Comment: Is this coming out of the `runserver`?  Nginx / Apache?  What kind of setup?

Comment: Hmm, I had not defined a 500.html template file in the templates folder. This apparently makes django use standard exception page i posted in my question with status code 200. I bit strange this is the default behavior. I've tried to look in the django sources but have not been able to find the reason for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DEBUG = False` it will try to run the `500.html` template.  Have you created that file?